# Flash Transparency of Overlapping Items

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs3

In Flash, I have a container with several overlapping children.  When I give this container an alpha value of .5, some of the children can be seen behind others that overlap them.  I would rather be able to take the whole thing as a composite image and blend it that way.

Any ideas?  cacheAsBitmap on the parent container doesn't have any effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[BlendMode.LAYER](http://www.zedia.net/2008/blendmodelayer-a-must-when-changing-alpha-of-a-displayobject-containing-other-displayobject/)

Answer (score 0):

Well, use Bitmap.draw() function... And then just alpha that image.

Like, put it into a MC and give an alpha value to it (for example).